# Extracting H1 title from list of web pages

Tags: macros, imacros

I have a long list of URLs and I want to extra the  title from each one and save it into an Microsoft Excel file.

I tried looking around for the code to do this but could not find it. I'm using iMacros for Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using internet explorer object along with MSHTML object library in excel VBA itself which may take off using 3rd party applications.

Comment: I'm certain this can be done very easily with iMacros. Unfortunately, I don't have the luxury to try out other methods at this time.

Comment: Extracting element details involves looping thatswhy i suggested you to choose that method.

Comment: Don't know enough about it, but I've used iMacros before for similar tasks with success

Answer (score 0):

You need first the list of URLs in a file (one URL in each line). Let's call it listOfUrls.csv (save as from Excel or just use a plain text file). You place that file in the iMacros/Datasources folder.

Then the macro itself:

```
SET !DATASOURCE listOfUrls.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1
SET !LOOP 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
TAB T=1
URL GOTO={{!COL1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TITLE ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=openThisInExcel.csv
```

Now you have to play the macro as Loop (look for "Play (Loop)"). Play is as many times as URLs you have in the list (set that in "Max:"). Then the macro will take you to each URL and get the title and save it into openThisInExcel.csv. That's it.

You may also want to keep the URL in the result CSV (so you know which Title correspond to which URL). Add the following before the last line or the line before that one (depending on the column order you want):

```
ADD !EXTRACT {{!URLCURRENT}}
```